# Change Spring configuraton on runtime

Tags: database, spring

I need to use two different properties in Spring application-context.xml file depending on the database that is used in the application.

Are there any way to change a property in the Spring context depending on java.sql.DatabaseMetaData before the context is initialized?

Thank you very much!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case it helped to inherit from Spring configuration class, and override methods in which I need to change a parameter. Thus, change in parameters occurs in runtime.

Refreshing context doesn't fit my needs as I need to load context in the correct way the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to refresh your context once you load data and change the configuration regarding the values from database.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--